# The element from @angular/material are not displaying propely

Tags: angular, button, angular-material

I put the exact code from the website of angular/material/button but I do not have the same result. My button are not clickable and they are all grey. I search online but could not found a solution.
What my code display :
[image]

What the angular code displaut with exaactely the same code:
[image]

This is my app.module.ts:
[image]

This is were the button should be:
[image]

And this is the result:
[image]

Like you can see, when I use the button from @angular/material they are all grey

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you have used - ideally in a codesandbox / codepen Did you follow this guide when installing Angular Material? https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: I am using a projet that was initialsie for me, but yes I follewed tutorial on how to install @angular/material. I will udpate iwth code

Comment: Available pre-built themes:

deeppurple-amber.css
indigo-pink.css
pink-bluegrey.css
purple-green.css
If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your styles.css file:

@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'; did you do this step?

Comment: did not do it, gona tried right now !

Comment: IT WORRRRRRRKED TAHNKS YOU SO MUCH, I spend the last 3 hours searchign whyyy. YO uare a savior ! Jsut starting angular for a school projet !